# Flutter: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' Error

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I am making Instagram clone app on Flutter. But when I go the profile screen, I get red screen background and this text (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' Error) on screen. How I can fix this?

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF4MR.png)

And this is my global.variable.dart file

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bagisla2/screens/add_post_screen.dart';
import 'package:bagisla2/screens/feed_screen.dart';
import 'package:bagisla2/screens/profile_screen.dart';
import 'package:bagisla2/screens/search_screen.dart';

const webScreenSize = 600;

List<Widget> homeScreenItems = [
  const FeedScreen(),
  const SearchScreen(),
  const AddPostScreen(),
  const Text('notifications'),
  ProfileScreen(
    uid: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
  ),
];
```

Comment: As mention in the error message the uid is null but the Profile screen constructor param must be non null string

Comment: How can I fix it bro? It is my lib file https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1YhHgzK7vlj227_GuYqI_yFeByPEkRFyG

Answer (score 0):

the error from the profile_screen.dart you just fix

```
getData() async {
  setState(() {
    isLoading = true;
  });
try {
  var userSnap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(widget.uid)
      .get();

  // get post lENGTH
  var postSnap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('posts')
      .where('uid', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .get();

  postLen = postSnap.docs.length;
  userData = userSnap.data()!;
  followers = userSnap.data()!['followers'].length;
  following = userSnap.data()!['following'].length;
  isFollowing = userSnap
      .data()!['followers']
      .contains(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
  setState(() {});
} catch (e) {
  showSnackBar(
    context,
    e.toString(),
  );
}
setState(() {
  isLoading = false;
});}
```

to

```
getData() async {
try {
  var userSnap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(widget.uid)
      .get();

  // get post lENGTH
  var postSnap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('posts')
      .where('uid', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .get();

  postLen = postSnap.docs.length;
  userData = userSnap.data()!;
  followers = userSnap.data()!['followers'].length;
  following = userSnap.data()!['following'].length;
  isFollowing = userSnap
      .data()!['followers']
      .contains(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
  setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
  });
} catch (e) {
  showSnackBar(
    context,
    e.toString(),
  );
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do a null-check before:

```
List<Widget> homeScreenItems = [
  const FeedScreen(),
  const SearchScreen(),
  const AddPostScreen(),
  const Text('notifications'),
  if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid != null)
    ProfileScreen(
      uid: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
    ),
];
```

Comment: Not worked bro :((

Comment: Did you restart the app? Thats definitely the fix for your error

Comment: I restarted but it is not resolved :((( I can send my lib folder for public   https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YhHgzK7vlj227_GuYqI_yFeByPEkRFyG?usp=sharing